# ffmpeg "Manifest too large" when downloading youtube video

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

### TL;DR

I'm trying to programmatically download **a part of** a YouTube video. The widely known procedure doesn't work for some videos and I'd like to overcome this situation.

---

### Context

I'm trying to programmatically download **a part of** a YouTube video. As described in [*How to download portion of video with youtube-dl command?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230481/how-to-download-portion-of-video-with-youtube-dl-command), you can achieve this by the following commands.

```sh
#Converts a human-readable URL to longer URLs for internal use.
~ $ youtube-dl --get-url 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POrfo478HRI'
https://r1---sn-3pm76n76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1597593009&ei=UQE5X7bXEYqO4QLs17KACQ&ip=10.100.238.99&id=o-AD0HfadoeimIbuf9t8Anru5X9V7cER08YyOz4iKZOCHL&itag=299&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=NV&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-3pm76n76%2Csn-oguesnze&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=17&initcwndbps=908750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=9205054989&dur=17931.000&lmt=1597347724488304&mt=1597571322&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=23883098&c=WEB&txp=7316222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgYDqTm0CnLfG0kxsYNrAdtAUYB7alnowiaBArU8R5bBwCIQDeCRDJHFO_PWcnbeFaJvip80deuboN4Pi1x3eRhJBxlQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAKTkyTIGVkbWWVx4lqFz77rOdG1FzkM5XuTnYOqtHT4oAiEA9u1R47jPz-mjj4DRXpqqqpUbfaFMW36KbG_pR2jovFM%3D&ratebypass=yes
https://r1---sn-3pm76n76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1597593009&ei=UQE5X7bXEYqO4QLs17KACQ&ip=10.100.238.99&id=o-AD0HfadoeimIbuf9t8Anru5X9V7cER08YyOz4iKZOCHL&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=NV&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-3pm76n76%2Csn-oguesnze&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=17&initcwndbps=908750&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=268945126&dur=17931.001&lmt=1597348111385641&mt=1597571322&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=23883098&c=WEB&txp=7311222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAK8XGu3vHucHwqERZ7TQniuvKEd-NTbMkwZbu8EXJ5E3AiEAiS7OYFOcsIrD2xp-AJNzucj1H9ZKMlmkCl_sU7__dZo%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAKTkyTIGVkbWWVx4lqFz77rOdG1FzkM5XuTnYOqtHT4oAiEA9u1R47jPz-mjj4DRXpqqqpUbfaFMW36KbG_pR2jovFM%3D&ratebypass=yes

#Stores the result to a variable.
~ $ url_video_part='https://r1---sn-3pm76n76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1597593009&ei=UQE5X7bXEYqO4QLs17KACQ&ip=10.100.238.99&id=o-AD0HfadoeimIbuf9t8Anru5X9V7cER08YyOz4iKZOCHL&itag=299&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=NV&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-3pm76n76%2Csn-oguesnze&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=17&initcwndbps=908750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=9205054989&dur=17931.000&lmt=1597347724488304&mt=1597571322&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=23883098&c=WEB&txp=7316222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgYDqTm0CnLfG0kxsYNrAdtAUYB7alnowiaBArU8R5bBwCIQDeCRDJHFO_PWcnbeFaJvip80deuboN4Pi1x3eRhJBxlQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAKTkyTIGVkbWWVx4lqFz77rOdG1FzkM5XuTnYOqtHT4oAiEA9u1R47jPz-mjj4DRXpqqqpUbfaFMW36KbG_pR2jovFM%3D&ratebypass=yes'

#Stores the result to a variable.
~ $ url_audio_part='https://r1---sn-3pm76n76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1597593009&ei=UQE5X7bXEYqO4QLs17KACQ&ip=10.100.238.99&id=o-AD0HfadoeimIbuf9t8Anru5X9V7cER08YyOz4iKZOCHL&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=NV&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-3pm76n76%2Csn-oguesnze&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=17&initcwndbps=908750&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=268945126&dur=17931.001&lmt=1597348111385641&mt=1597571322&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=23883098&c=WEB&txp=7311222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAK8XGu3vHucHwqERZ7TQniuvKEd-NTbMkwZbu8EXJ5E3AiEAiS7OYFOcsIrD2xp-AJNzucj1H9ZKMlmkCl_sU7__dZo%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAKTkyTIGVkbWWVx4lqFz77rOdG1FzkM5XuTnYOqtHT4oAiEA9u1R47jPz-mjj4DRXpqqqpUbfaFMW36KbG_pR2jovFM%3D&ratebypass=yes'

#Downloads the video for one minute from 12:45.
~ $ ffmpeg    -ss 12:45 -i "${url_video_part}"    -ss 12:45 -i "${url_audio_part}"    -t 1:00 output.mkv
frame= 3600 fps= 49 q=-1.0 Lsize=   27047kB time=00:00:59.99 bitrate=3692.9kbits/s speed=0.813x
```

This does work perfectly.

---

### Problem

For some videos<sup>†1</sup>, the internal URLs are of the form `https://manifest.googlevideo.com/...` instead of `https://RANDOM-STRING.googlevideo.com/...` as in the example above.

```sh
~ $ youtube-dl --get-url 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRMfnvLODZQ'
https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/dash/expire/1597593866/ei/qgQ5X5maN8-ilQSu15W4CQ/ip/10.100.238.99/id/KRMfnvLODZQ.1/source/yt_live_broadcast/requiressl/yes/hfr/all/as/fmp4_audio_clear%2Cwebm_audio_clear%2Cwebm2_audio_clear%2Cfmp4_sd_hd_clear%2Cwebm2_sd_hd_clear/force_finished/1/vprv/1/keepalive/yes/fexp/23883098/itag/0/playlist_type/DVR/sparams/expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Chfr%2Cas%2Cforce_finished%2Cvprv%2Citag%2Cplaylist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRQIhANYKQvKTN8BRmhp7--4tQp9aqRp_qIGjh472BTYLyJ62AiAautFF86xGDHOe7mYlYaZ1W86EM4k2e6UiJS9Q91dMog%3D%3D
https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/dash/expire/1597593866/ei/qgQ5X5maN8-ilQSu15W4CQ/ip/10.100.238.99/id/KRMfnvLODZQ.1/source/yt_live_broadcast/requiressl/yes/hfr/all/as/fmp4_audio_clear%2Cwebm_audio_clear%2Cwebm2_audio_clear%2Cfmp4_sd_hd_clear%2Cwebm2_sd_hd_clear/force_finished/1/vprv/1/keepalive/yes/fexp/23883098/itag/0/playlist_type/DVR/sparams/expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Chfr%2Cas%2Cforce_finished%2Cvprv%2Citag%2Cplaylist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRQIhANYKQvKTN8BRmhp7--4tQp9aqRp_qIGjh472BTYLyJ62AiAautFF86xGDHOe7mYlYaZ1W86EM4k2e6UiJS9Q91dMog%3D%3D
```

And downloading such videos always fails.

```sh
~ $ ffmpeg    -ss 12:45 -i "${url_video_part}"    -ss 12:45 -i "${url_audio_part}"    -t 1:00 output.mkv
[dash @ 0x55fa6a1a4400] Manifest too large: 3776722
https://manifest.googlevideo.com/...: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Please note downloading full of such videos using `youtube-dl` alone succeeds.

<sub>†1: As far as we tested, recently (e.g. yesterday) uploaded videos have such URLs and when we retry the same `youtube-dl --get-url` command after a day or so, we get "innocent" URLs like in the first example.</sub>

---

### Questions

How can I download parts of such videos

- by specifying additional options for `ffmpeg`,
- by somehow forcefully retrieving internal URLs of the form `https://RANDOM-STRING.googlevideo.com/...`,
- or by something which I have no idea at all?

My current workaround is just to wait for a day or two until the internal URLs change, which is much slower than downloading the full video and then cropping it.

---

### Environments

```sh
~ $ lsb_release -d
Description:    Arch Linux

~ $ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100

~ $ youtube-dl --version
2020.07.28
```

Comment: Are you trying to download a live video? Or a video that was live not so long ago? I would recommend to use `curl` to get more information about what kind of response are you receiving (with the `-v` option to enable verbose output): `curl -v 'https://manifest.googlevideo.com/...'`

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I'm trying download a live archive which has already finished being live-streamed but not so much time has been past since that. Though actually I've already tried `curl -v 'https://manifest.googlevideo.com/...' `, I didn't know how to read the output with many similar lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two workarounds.

---

## 1. Just wait for a day or two.

As described in the OP, you can just wait for a few days for the internal URLs to be changed<sup>†1</sup> from `https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/dash/...` to `https://r1---sn-3pm76n76.googlevideo.com/...`.

As far as I tested, this takes at least a whole day for long (7-10 hours) videos.

---

## 2. Use HLS instead of DASH.

### 2.1 Workaround

By the following steps, you can download the video right away.

1. `url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkP-hgGJdvY'`

<sub>(I chose this URL as an example because `youtube-dl --get-url "${url}"` returns `https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/...` at the time of writing this answer.)</sub>

2. `curl "${url}"`
3. From the output of `curl`, extract the URL `internal_url` of the form `https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/...`. Note that this URL contains `/hls_variant/` instead of `/dash/`.
4. `ffmpeg -i "${internal_url}"` with or without arbitrary options to download the video.

One liner of the step 2 and 3:

```sh
curl --silent "${url}" | grep -o 'https:\\/\\/[^"]\+googlevideo.com\\/[^"]\+' | grep 'hls_variant' | sed 's/\\//g'
```

### 2.2 Known Issue

Even by the method above, for a long (2+ hours) live archive which has finished being live-streamed recently (e.g. hours or a day ago), **only exactly last 2 hours of the whole video can be downloaded**<sup>†2</sup> even if you can play the video on a browser or the official app with no problem. This problem is not specific to `ffmpeg` and actually `youtube-dl`'s GitHub repository has a related issue: [*Youtube: Only downloading last 2 hours of 3 hour video. (with hack as a workaround) #26330*](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26330). (By the way, the OP of the issue includes a workaround of this problem, which I don't write here since I don't tested.)

---

## 3 Conclusion

Taking †1 and †2 into account, it seems the problem occurs when the YouTube server-side process of the target video has not completely been finished. Although I have no idea at all how to, probably there should be some elegant way to overcome the only-last-two-hour problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to skip the manifest file and get the final URL by using `youtube-dl --youtube-skip-dash-manifest`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm going to add this back to my [original answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230481/how-to-download-portion-of-video-with-youtube-dl-command)

Comment: This will not work for recently finished livestreams that were longer than 2 hours. The resulting downloaded file will have only the last 2 hours of the video. Related: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26330

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on this, I ran into this issue, and some digging found that ffmpeg [merged a patch to fix this](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/3249c757aed678780e22e99a1a49f4672851bca9) back in September. While it hasn't made it into a release yet as of Feb 6, 2021, it should be in whatever release follows after 4.3.1 (perhaps 4.3.2 or 4.4).

Helpfully, it also explains how the problem came about - a "soft-limit" for cases where nothing was known got reinterpreted as a hard limit, and the September patch fixed the misinterpretation by removing the limit entirely.

Comment: I'm trying HLS command: it returns empty string or, without `--silent` flag, an error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: $https`. However, my link is downloadable as a whole.